# Nvidia driver installed successfully, but not activated

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

My Ubuntu 12.04 only shows up black screen when starting up some days ago suddenly. Since I can desktop through recovery mode (resume in recovery mode, and the resolution is wrong), I  believe there's something wrong with my video card driver. So I go to nvidia's website, download the driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.44.run, and installed it successfully.

Now, while I can get the following output with `lspci | grep -i nvidia`

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT215 [GeForce GT 335M] (rev a2)

**the driver seems not to be activated.**

When I start up NVIDIA X Server settings, it shows up a message box saying

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.

But I do run xnvidia-config successfully, and also reboot the system.

What's more, the "Additional Drivers" is blank, saying

> No proprietary drivers are in use on this system

Could anybody give some hints on how to deal with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As 13.04 has been released, and there had been some problems before I upgraded to 12.04, reinstalling my ubuntu seems to be a good idea to me, so, I did it.

Really enjoy 13.04!

Comment: where do you download this 310 driver

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing the same problem. Now that you asked it, I wanted to fix in my computer as well. So here is how you do it.

**EDIT:** `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`. This will just create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Next do

`sudo software-properties-gtk`

You should see something like this

[image]

Select `Additional Drivers` tab and select the latest NVIDIA driver as I have selected here.

Now reboot. This reboot might take a long time. No need to worry. If it takes more than 10 minutes with the black screen, even after rebooting, restart with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or even hard reset (keep pressing the power button as long as needed). It should work properly now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, thefourtheye! Sadly, "sudo software-properties-gtk" have no "additional driver" tab on my laptop

Comment: I have updated my answer with the step to install nvidia drivers in Ubuntu way. Kindly do that as well.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I installed ubuntu 13.04, so problems gone.

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is that screenshot from? When I run `sudo software-properties-gtk` on my Ubuntu 12.04.x box, the screen does not have a tab labeled 'Additional Drivers'.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest running this command to uninstall the driver and installing it via apt
`sudo nvidia-installer --uninstall`
To install the driver with apt run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-310` (you may need to use `nvidia-current` or `nvidia-310-updates` package, I don't recall which name 12.04 uses for the nvidia 310 driver)
You may want to add the [xswat ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates?field.series_filter=precise) to get newer drivers
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Comment: Sorry for being so late.

I got my problems fixed with installing 13.04 after several days off. I will try your advice if problem occurred again in future.

Thank you, GM-Script-Writer-62850!