# My hardware can handle OpenGL 3.2 but my system throws error related to the OpenGL version that my computer supports

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I have the following hardware configuration -

1. NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]
2. Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller

According to NVIDIA's website (http://www.nvidia.in/object/product-geforce-gt-525m-in.html), my system supports OpenGL 4.4 but when I try to run some code from https://github.com/tomdalling/opengl-series, I get the following error -

```
Unable to create OpenGL context
ERROR: glfwOpenWindow failed. Can your hardware handle OpenGL 3.2?
```

Please help.

P.S: I am a newbie

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the latest driver for your video card:

Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then restart your system to see if proprietary drivers helped to get OpenGL 3.2 support.

You can see the supported version using the `nvidia-settings` utility:

[image]

Comment: I wrote the two lines in my terminal. Then I restarted my computer. But I got a new error saying - 
"Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Unable to create OpenGL context
ERROR: glfwOpenWindow failed. Can your hardware handle OpenGL 3.2?".

Comment: When I tried to open NVIDIA X Server Settings I got an error prompt saying "You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server."

Comment: Now try `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and restart again

Comment: Alternatively check the first answer posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286654/nvidia-driver-installed-successfully-but-not-activated

Comment: I think my system crashed. After I restarted, neither the desktop launched nor the unity plugin. A black screen was displayed and the crosshair changed into a cross. I opened the terminal using the shortcut ctrl+alt+T and then did sudo remove nvidia* and then sudo reboot. Now I am having trouble with my monitor resolution which cannot be found. I'll try fixing all this and then redo the steps which you told. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an [Optimus Laptop](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html).  As such, this [Ubuntu Wiki Entry on Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).  You did not buy a laptop with a full NVIDIA board.  The Intel board computes the pixels etc and offloads the rendering to the NVIDIA board, under high load.

Set up your X Server installation to use your Intel Chipset, then install the Bumblebee on top of it