# Activating installed Nvidia videa drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 14.10, xserver

I Have installed several video drivers from the software centre and I have installed the official driver from Nvidia.com and none of them show up in the additional drivers application. I did what this suggested but they still do not show [Nvidia driver installed successfully, but not activated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286654/nvidia-driver-installed-successfully-but-not-activated) .
The reason I am trying to use a different driver is because when I use the nouveau or the nvidia 331 driver I can't use my nvidia card, when I use the kernal and VDPAU 340 driver I get graphical glitches.

output of `lspci | grep VGA` `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

output of `lspci | grep 3D`  `02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)`

the intel card goes to the monitor port but the nvidia card is for rendering

Comment: Hi, can you update the question with the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, type `lspci | grep VGA` and take a note of your Graphic card model, just to make sure it is NVidia .

You are probably using the xorg open sourced driver right now and high resolution can create problems, as far as I'm aware.

To install the unofficial drivers, follow these steps :

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and login with your credentials. Now as root, run the following commands :

`killall -9 lightdm` **(Unity)**

or,

`killall -9 kdm` **(KDE)**

or,

`killall -9 gdm` **(Gnome)**

Now, type :

`killall -9 Xorg`

And run the following commands :

`sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current`

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-current`

Comment: When I ran the purge commands, nothing was removed, when I did the update it could not find utopic packages from that ppa, when I installed nvidia current it only removed a driver I had installed. Note: I did not use your command to kill lightdm, I used sudo service lightdm stop.

Comment: Have you selected all the packages in the Software Sources?

Comment: So after I install a driver via software centre or a .run, I must select it in software sources?

Comment: output of `lspci | grep VGA` `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

output of `lspci | grep 3D` `02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)`

Comment: No. Not necessary to do it. Just make sure everything is check marked and perform the above steps.

Comment: I have every ppa even remotely related to drivers enabled

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then try the steps in the answer. Skip the repository step if you already have the repository.

Comment: I have followed many answers to similar problems and have run the update and upgrade command numerous times, this problem may be specific to my hardware and Ubuntu version. There may not be a fix unfortunately.

Comment: this ppa you pointed me to does not have any utopic packages http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the drivers are working

Comment: Oh, I must have seen the tag. YOu should have probably mentioned that in the question that you are using 14.10. Yes, this is a issue in 14.10 as the graphic drivers are not yet upstream. Anyway, good job :)